# How to make my xml code fit on all devices

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgpic"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LonelyMoviePageActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movieImgView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/gmp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="Gravity"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:text="(2016)"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="In a Series:"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seriesOrNoText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:text="No"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Rating:"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieRatingText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:text="R"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbg"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbg"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried that code on my phone, it worked perfectly, however, I tried on my mom's phone, it was awfull, any idea how do I make it fit on all devices Online sites say that it's better to use a constraint layout, however, that would mess up all I've done, any help. I don't have an emulator installed on android studio, cuz some answer was involving it.

Comment: `Online sites say that it's better to use a constraint layout, however, that would mess up all I've done` overall it's probably better to use constraint layout, assuming you know how to use it. using values like `70dp` is way too big to assume it'll work on all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `LinearLayouts` and add one `ConstraintLayout` at the top level, which constrains `Views` to each other including the edge of the screen. Meaning it will condense *(within reason)* and expand to fit the screen size as there is no need to hardcode `dp` sizes
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Example of buttons in the middle.

Two vertical guidelines `guideline1 @ 10%` and `guideline2 @ 90%`

Two buttons `btnNext` and `btnPrevious`

The two buttons are constrained to each other thus pushing them together.

The `btnNext` is constrained to `guideline1` thus pushing it 10% off the left side of the screen `(@ 10%)`.

The `btnPrevious` is constrained to `guideline2` thus pushing it 10% off the right side of the screen `(@ 90%)`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" <-- Make an invisible line at 10% mark on the screen.
    />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" <-- Make an invisible line at 90% mark on the screen.
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnPrevious" <-- Push to btnNext 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1" <-- Push to 10% mark of the screen.
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnNext" <-- Push to btnPrevious 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2" <-- Push to 90% mark of the screen.
        android:text="Previous"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If I have two items on the same line for example like the next button and the previous, I could never have them in the center when using a constraint layout

Comment: Sure you can, why do you think you couldn't?

Comment: @MarkGeorge  Just guessing from your margins that you have on the two buttons. You could use vertical guidelines. Say 1 is at 10% and the other is at 90%. You would then constrain the two buttons to each other and 1 button to the 10% guideline and the other to the 90% guideline.

Comment: can you explain what you just said

Comment: I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to scalibility is to never hardcode dp values on your views.
Instead use a ConstraintLayout and constrain your views.
I recommend looking into the 'guideline' view, it's very useful when trying to make scalable apps.